# Передача данных от апплета к html-документу

Tags: applet, html, java, javascript

Добрый день! Пишет вам совсем новичок в `java`, а javascript и вовсе не изучал никогда. На эклипсе я написал апплет без видимой части на странице, который затем экспортировал в файл `test.jar`. Апплет имеет входную точку через класс `View_files_folders` и выглядит данный класс следующим образом:

```
public class View_files_folders extends Applet
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  public AttributFilesFolders readDir(String pDir)
  {
      AttributFilesFolders AFF = new AttributFilesFolders();
      AFF.setPath(pDir);
      return AFF;
  }
}
```

Как видно из кода, функция `readDir` возвращает класс `AttributFilesFolders()` принимая параметр: директория папки - `pDir`; Класс `AttributFilesFolders()` содержит в себе следующие публичные функции:

- `getAllCount()`. Подсчет всех файлов и 
         папок во всех содержащихся 
         подкаталогах. Возвращает целое число.
- `getCount()`. Подсчет всех файлов и
       папок в каталоге. Возвращает целое число.
- `getItem(int number)`. Возвращает строковый массив - информацию о файле или папке с указанным номером.
- `ViewFolder()`. Возвращает строковый массив - обзор папки (файлы и папки).

Кроме того написан `html` документ взаимодействующий с файлом `test.jar`:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251"> 
<title>Работа с test.jar</title>
</head>
<body>
Введите директорию, которую хотите просмотреть:
<form>
<input type="text" NAME=mytext SIZE=50>
<input type="button" VALUE="Обзор папок и файлов"
onClick="document.applets[0].readDir(eval(this.form.mytext.value))">
</form>
  <applet code="test.jar">
   </applet>    
</body>
</html>
```

Вопрос такой как получить обратные данные из апплета и вывести к примеру строковый массив функции `ViewFolder()` или вывести число функции `getCount()` к примеру в этом же `html`-документе в виде таблицы? Покажите простенький пример, чтобы стало понятно как это делается...

Answer (score 1):

Так и не дождался я толковой помощи от пользователей хэшкода. Сделал следующим образом. Подскажите правильно ли я сделал, с учетом моего задания? Спрашиваю потому что javascript не знаю вовсе, делал просто по аналогии с другими языками и по учебникам javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251"> 
<title>Работа с test.jar</title>
</head>
<body>

<applet code="test.jar" width="1" height="1" id="dir_applet"></applet>

<center>Введите директорию, которую хотите просмотреть:
<form>
<input type="text" id="mytext" SIZE=50>
<input type="button" VALUE="Вывод папок и файлов" onClick="InputData()">
</form>
</center>

<table border="1">
<tr>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function InputData()
    {
       var dirApplet = document.getElementById("dir_applet");
       var path = document.getElementById("mytext").value;
       var ListFiles = dirApplet.readDir(path).ViewFolder();
       for (var i=0; i<ListFiles.length; i++)
       {
         document.write("<td>"+ListFiles[i]+"</td>");
       }
    }   
  </script>
</tr>  
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Надеюсь тут есть знатоки java и javascript, которые смогут поставить диагноз и совет мне в чем ошибка. Потому что пока это все не работает, вернее не выводит папки и файлы, как я хотел. Если кому интересно можете тут посмотреть [test.html](http://java.book-fan.ru/test.html)

Comment: Спасибо, что опубликовали своё решение. )